# Sencha Touch 2: How to FIlter on a Association's Store?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-touch

I have an issue trying to filter the results of an association. I have a list of categories with many subcategories. I'm using MVC architecture. So, here is an example what I'm trying to do:

```js
var subcategories = category.subcategories();

subcategories.filter("title", "some text");
subcategories.each( function (item) { console.log(item.get('title')); } );
```

Some how the filter is not applying. It always return the original store, same amount of records, etc.

I'm also doing this:

```js
var subcategories = category.subcategories();

subcategories.filterBy(function(item) {
   console.log( item );
   return (item.get('title') == 'some text');
});
```

But the console.log it's not running even once! The store is full of records, I've cehcked that

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a late answer, but it will help many people who are searching solution for the same problem.

The key is to calling **`setRemoteFilter(false)`** on Association's Store.

```
var products = user.products();
products.setRemoteFilter(false); // without this line, filter on Association's Store didn't work
var categorieFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    property: 'categories',
    value   : 'Electronic'
});
products.setFilters(categorieFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple questions:

1. What version of Sencha Touch are you using?
2. When using associations in Sencha Touch you still need to do a lot of work by yourself. It's not completely automatic. For example you need to add all subcatagories manually to each category object. Are you doing this?

Comment: ST2.2. I thought Associations worked that way. But I have to specify remoteFilter so it works automatically doing requests to server side API. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't believe it would automatically load subcats and assign them to proper categories. You need to load subcategores store manually and then go and add necessary ones to their categories.